# Speeding up pure python nested list operations with numba

Tags: python, list, performance, numba

I have been tasked with writing a pure-python implementation of blending two images utilizing image pyramids. I cannot use NumPy, however I am allowed to use Numba. However, I cannot get my functions to work, even though operations in them are supported (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#).
Here is my code:

```
@jit
def blur_image(image: list[list[list[float], kernel: list[list[float]]) -> list[list[list[float]:
    PADDING: int = 2
    height: int = len(image)
    width: int = len(image[0])
    padded_img= create_empty_image(height + 2 * PADDING, width + 2 * PADDING)
    output_img = create_empty_image(height, width)

    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            padded_img[i + PADDING][j + PADDING] = image[i][j]

    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            sum_r: float = 0.
            sum_g: float = 0.
            sum_b: float = 0.
            for k in range(5):
                for l in range(5):
                    sum_r += kernel[k][l] * padded_img[i + k][j + l][0]
                    sum_g += kernel[k][l] * padded_img[i + k][j + l][1]
                    sum_b += kernel[k][l] * padded_img[i + k][j + l][2]

            output_img[i][j][0] = min(int(sum_r), 255)
            output_img[i][j][1] = min(int(sum_g), 255)
            output_img[i][j][2] = min(int(sum_b), 255)

    return output_img

@jit
def create_empty_image(height: int, width: int) -> img_as_list:
    return [[[0., 0., 0.] for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)]
```

The kernel here is a standard 5 x 5 gaussian kernel;

```
    gaussian_kernel: list[list[float]] = [[1, 4, 6, 4, 1],
                                          [4, 16, 24, 16, 4],
                                          [6, 24, 36, 24, 6],
                                          [4, 16, 24, 16, 4],
                                          [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]] # * (1/256.), but I multiply it somewhere else
```

Now from what I understand, operations on nested list are allowed in numba, but I am getting an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/krzysztof/lab5/lab_5.py", line 258, in <module>
    orange_upscaled = blur_image(orange_copy, gaussian_kernel)
  File "/home/krzysztof/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 487, in _compile_for_args
    raise e
  File "/home/krzysztof/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 420, in _compile_for_args
    return_val = self.compile(tuple(argtypes))
  File "/home/krzysztof/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 1197, in compile
    cres = compiler.compile_ir(typingctx=self.typingctx,
  File "/home/krzysztof/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 754, in compile_ir
    norw_cres = compile_local(func_ir.copy(), norw_flags)
  File "/home/krzysztof/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 750, in compile_local
    return pipeline.compile_ir(func_ir=the_ir, lifted=lifted,
  File "/home/krzysztof/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 462, in compile_ir
    return self._compile_ir()
  File "/home/krzysztof/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 527, in _compile_ir
    return self._compile_core()
  File "/home/krzysztof/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 499, in _compile_core
    raise e
  File "/home/krzysztof/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 486, in _compile_core
    pm.run(self.state)
  File "/home/krzysztof/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 368, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "/home/krzysztof/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 356, in run
    self._runPass(idx, pass_inst, state)
  File "/home/krzysztof/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 35, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/krzysztof/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 318, in _runPass
    enforce_no_dels(internal_state.func_ir)
  File "/home/krzysztof/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/ir_utils.py", line 2194, in enforce_no_dels
    raise CompilerError(msg, loc=dels[0].loc)
numba.core.errors.CompilerError: Failed in object mode pipeline (step: remove phis nodes)
Illegal IR, del found at: del $158for_iter.3

File "lab_5.py", line 204:
def blur_image(image: img_as_list, kernel: list[list[float]]) -> img_as_list:
    <source elided>
            sum_b: float = 0.
            for k in range(5):
            ^


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I apologize in advance if this is a newbie error, however I've tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Numba is made to speed up code mainly operating on arrays. It supports typed lists and typed dicts but they are not so fast. AFAIK, It does not support reflected list/dict anymore, that is default dynamic CPython list/dict. Numba refuses to compile this code since it operates on reflected lists. Numba cannot speed this kind of code due to dynamically-typed objects (ie. this is not really possible). Put it shortly, please read the [documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html) carefully and use Numpy arrays.

Comment: @JérômeRichard The thing is, I am not allowed to use NumPy. Would reverting to a numba version that suppoerted reflected lists make this code work?

Comment: By the way, your input memory layout is inefficient, please consider using array CxHxW instead of HxWxC if this is possible. The latter is good for low-level vectorization. Note there are libraries to do that much more efficiently than you do (eg. OpenCV).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes I know, the first part of the task was to implement the blending using openCV, the second part was doing it all in pure python (with c/c++ or numba insertions) to compare the speedup given by optimized libraries

Comment: Numba never really supported reflected list efficiently because reflected lists are fundamentally inefficient. Cython supports them but the speed up is generally small and disappointing (eg. <20% faster). Besides the performance, lists also use a lot more memory due to each item being a reference to a dynamic object and not just a native int/float. Whatever the code/module/method use to operate on such input, be prepared to get a code several order of magnitude slower than an optimized native code. Reflected lists are a dead-end.

Answer (score 0):

Numba project is focused on dealing with Numpy arrays, and I don't recommend Python lists for image processing. There's no reason to do that even for an educational purpose, because using Numba means you have already braced yourself for hard work to tune the performance.

Anyway if you insist on doing that, there is an experimental feature on Python nested lists - [Typed list](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pysupported.html#typed-list). You have to tweak your code like this.(I didn't port type hints.)

```
from numba import njit
from numba.typed import List

@njit
def blur_image(image, kernel):
    ...

@njit
def create_empty_image(height, width):
    return List([List([List([0., 0., 0.]) for _ in range(width)]) for _ in range(height)])

gaussian_kernel = List([List([float(e) for e in row]) for row in [
    [1, 4, 6, 4, 1],
    [4, 16, 24, 16, 4],
    [6, 24, 36, 24, 6],
    [4, 16, 24, 16, 4],
    [1, 4, 6, 4, 1],
]])
```

Comment: Thank you, although I managed to tweak some of my functions to be compatible with numba, and performed the task anyway. I will not be deleting the question since someone someday (students year below me) might find it helpful.